# Can't find any QTC (quantum tunneling composite)

Tags: quantum-tunneling

As per the title, I can't find any QTC to buy online. I may be dumb or just looking in the wrong places. Is it that uncommon? Are there any places that sell it locally in Melbourne, or is it just online? Apologies if this is the wrong forum as this question isn't about theory.

Comment: Could you perhaps tell us more about this "quantum tunneling composite"?

Comment: I searched  for " quantum tunneling composites" and learned they are metallic constructions   used in pressure sensors, and if you google "pressure sensor"  a number of sellers come up.